How to manage global state in SwiftUI and persist it
Continuing learning SwiftUI (which is so much fun) I'm doubting the way I'm managing (and storing) global state in my app and storing it. There are two categories of data that I need to manage. The first is an object from a third party library, it contains the logged in state of the user and the tokens to access the API. The second is some data that will be required for almost all API requests like the chosen server, the user's ID, and one or two other tidbits.
My current solution
The two categories of data each have a class to represent them, one, OIDAuthState, is from the third-party library I'm using. The other, Profile, is a class I've written. Both classes are Codable so they can be stored.
class Profile: Codable {
    var serverURL: String?
    var userID: String?
    // A few more fields all optional
}

I'm using a model class, AuthModel as an environment object which holds both data classes so I have access to the data everywhere in my app.
class AuthModel: ObservableObject {
    var authState: OIDAuthState?
    @Published var profile: Profile?
    @Published var isAuthenticated = false

    func login() async {
        // Perform login, if successful get an OIDAuthState instance from the third-party library
        self.authState = authState
        self.isAuthenticated = authState?.isAuthorized == true
    }
}

In the entry point I initialize the AuthModel and pass it to the root view that is displayed. That way I have access to the data in all my views.
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var authModel = AuthModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if authModel.isAuthenticated {
                ContentView().environmentObject(authModel)
            } else {
                LoginFlowView().environmentObject(authModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

Most of my doubts come from my Profile class. All fields are added at different moments during login, so they are all optional. This causes a lot of optional unwrapping/chaining making the code ugly. Additionally, the data from the Profile class is mostly used to make API requests, I get it from the environment in my views and pass it as input to my models that make the requests. Going through the views feels as an unnecessary step.
Both the OIDAuthState and Profile will be saved so users remain logged in between app sessions, but I haven't figured out how or when to write them.

Anything sensitive should go in keychain, anything unimportant and small can go in app storage or scene storage

It’s best to remove the old StateObject and use .task to call your async funcs and save the result

@malhal you mean to not have the login method set the published values but return the data to the caller of the method? By setting the data on the AuthModel class I only have to add the AuthModel instance to the environment to have access to the data everywhere in my app (in the views at least). There isn't an easier way to make data globally available in an app? Especially in the model layer as I'll likely need the data there most often.

Everything I found only suggested to save the tokens (which are on the OIDAuthState) in keychain @loremipsum, but the OIDAuthState class is a complex object and the documentation suggested to have it created by the library by having a user sign in. I don't want users to sign in each time they use the app so I'm afraid I'll have to store the OIDAuthState securely somehow.

Just remove the class and you should be good

I’m sure the docs tell you what parts you need to save to persist the object. Look at the docs.

The object is a subclass of NSSecureCoding, so I should be able to persist it securely using the Keyed Archiver. Trying this in the simulator fails because the volume is read only, I expect that that is a simulator problem.
